# Parse Subscribed Channel not Showing in Channel List

Tags: parse-platform, push-notification

I am trying to setup my app to send push notifications via Parse to my users.  Each of my ~56k users is subscribed to a channel unique to their user ID.  In my Core tab I see a user subscribed to a specific channel.  But when I go to the Push Notification Composer and attempt to filter down by channels, that channel does not show up.

Why would a user show being subscribed to a channel, but that channel is unavailable to selected from the drop down?  Also, is there a (relatively easy) way to export all channels that all users are subscribed to?

Thanks,
Adam

Comment: I have the same problem, I can't see the list of channels, you get any solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve my problem by understanding the data shown in the channel list drop down a little better.

When I began searching for a specific channel and it was not found, the last item in the drop down list is "Add channel_name".  Clicking that item will force the entered channel to be selected in the list.

Running a query against the Core data to ensure the channel really has subscribers was also key to ensure the channel existed.

Adam