# Parse.com for Android. Channel not showing in channel list

Tags: android, parse-platform, show, channel

This post is not working
[same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32185854/parse-subscribed-channel-not-showing-in-channel-list)

My code :

```
final ParseInstallation installation = ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation();
        installation.addAllUnique("channels", Arrays.asList(mAndroidTestChannal2));
        installation.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
            @Override
            public void done(ParseException e) {
                ParsePush.subscribeInBackground(mAndroidTestChannal2, new SaveCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void done(ParseException e) {
                        if (e == null) {
                            installation.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
                                @Override
                                public void done(ParseException e) {
                                    if (e == null) {
                                        Log.d("com.parse.push", "successfully subscribed to the broadcast channel.");
                                    } else {
                                        Log.e("com.parse.push", "failed to subscribe for push", e);
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                            Log.d("com.parse.push", "successfully subscribed to the broadcast channel.");
                        } else {
                            Log.e("com.parse.push", "failed to subscribe for push", e);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

All callbacks goes to successfully log, but I can't see channel in drop down list in push dashboard.

My main problem is that i can't receive push notifications from parse (dashboard said that push was sent to 0 devices.). I tried to register for different channel (base in production with over 100k devices), but fails with this situation.
 What do I wrong ?
parse sdk - last, 1.13.0

Answer (score 0):

Parse.com is closing soon, better use Google Cloud Messaging )

Comment: That's not my decision.